# How to make a for loop to fetch links from firebase with flutter?

Tags: loops, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to have a for loop that gives a number which is increased by one every time.
something like

```
    for (int i; i > 0; i <= 4){
       var link = snapshot.data.documents[i].data['Link'];
       var uploader = snapshot.data.documents[i].data['Uploader'];
       var likes = snapshot.data.documents[i].data['Likes'];
       .....
       and then i = i++
    }.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a basic for-loop, this should work:

```
for (int i=1; i <= 4; i++) {  // 1,2,3,4
   var link = snapshot.data.documents[i].data['Link'];
   var uploader = snapshot.data.documents[i].data['Uploader'];
   var likes = snapshot.data.documents[i].data['Likes'];
   .....
   //and then i = i++  // don't need this
}.
```

Comment: Thanks, this should add 1 to `i` every time until the , right?

Comment: it doesn't repeat every time there is a link, it just do it 1 time.